# Theorem 8.2.5 in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

In the proof of Theorem 8.2.5 in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis, a linear operator $A: Y'\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by $Ag=(g(Tx_1), g(Tx_2),\cdots,  g(Tx_2))$ where $g\in Y'$, the dual space of the normed space $Y$. But, there is no restriction on $Y$ as a real normed space. So in general $X\& Y$ are complex normed spaces. So how can we assume $A$ from $Y'\to \mathbb{R}^n$? I think it must be from  $Y'\to \mathbb{C}^n$. Am I correct?

Comment: A map $\phi:Y'\to\mathbb{C}^n$ is naturally a map into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it should be $\mathbb C^n$. It is probably a consequence of the author trying to allow the ambiguity of the field be either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Did you actually go through the proof? If I take the field as $\mathbb{C}$, does the rest of the proof work?

Comment: Yes, it does. $ $